# (Python) Transform dataframe: parse rows if more than one value is given and add to corresponding given rows of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Sample dataset I have looks like this:

| Language | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Russian | 1000 |
| English | 1500 |
| Spanish | 500 |
| Arabic,Russian, English, Spanish | 2 |
| Arabic, English | 15 |

I want it to transform so that the result looks like this:

| Language | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Russian | 1002 |
| English | 1517 |
| Spanish | 502 |
| Arabic | 17 |

So what happened is that, I parsed rows that contained more than one language. Added up them to languages that were already given. If it was not given (in this case: Arabic) created the new one.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and last aggregate sum:

```
df = (df.assign(Language=df.Language.str.split(','))
        .explode('Language')
        .groupby('Language', as_index=False, sort=False)
        .sum())
print (df)
  Language  Count
0  Russian   1002
1  English   1517
2  Spanish    502
3   Arabic     17
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), and [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
out = (df
   .assign(Language=df['Language'].str.split(',\s*'))
   .explode('Language')
   .groupby('Language', as_index=False, sort=False).sum()
)
```

output:

```
  Language  Count
0  Russian   1002
1  English   1517
2  Spanish    502
3   Arabic     17
```